# How to close an express and a websocket server on the git bash terminal close on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, terminal, git-bash, exit

I want my node.js app close on git bash terminal window close ( without pressing ctrl+c )
I tried SIGTERM SIGINT SIGHUP SIGWHATEVER, it doesn't work, the app won't exit, I get 'the port blabla is already in use, when trying to run it again'

here's the code

```
const server = app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port 8000`);
});

process.on('SIGQUIT', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGQUIT');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGTERM');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGINT');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGBREAK', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGBREAK');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGHUP', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGHUP');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGUSR1', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGUSR1');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGUSR2', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGUSR2');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGTTOU', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGTTOU');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGTTIN', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGTTIN');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGTSTP', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGTSTP');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGCHLD', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGCHLD');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGTTOU', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGTTOU');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGTRAP', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGTRAP');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGABRT', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGABRT');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGFPE', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGFPE');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGBUS', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGBUS');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGSEGV', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGSEGV');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGPIPE', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGPIPE');
    process.exit();
});
process.on('SIGSYS', () => {
    wss.close();
    server.close();
    writeFileSync('./1.txt', 'SIGSYS');
    process.exit();
});
```

I start the server with this script in my package.json
"ts-node ./src/server/server.ts"
and when it did start I just close the terminal, and nothing happens, when I reopen the terminal and start the server again I get

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1893:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1941:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:2029:7)
at new WebSocketServer (D:\coding\media-buyer-ui\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket-server.js:102:20)
at Object. (D:\coding\media-buyer-ui\src\server\server.ts:32:13)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
at Module.m._compile (D:\coding\media-buyer-ui\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
at Object.require.extensions. [as .ts] (D:\coding\media-buyer-ui\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -4091,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 8080

Comment: You need to make more detailed information, and  provides a minimal example, Can you read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: For this question I don't. What did you not understand??? I asked HOW TO CLOSE A NODEJS APP WHEN CLOSING A GIT BASH TERMINAL WITH A CLOSE BUTTON WITHOUT CTRL+C. I TRIED ALL SIGNAL CODES, IT SEEMS NOT SENDING ANYTHIG AT ALL. SHOULD I ASK THE QUESTION IN JAPANESE FOR YOU????

Comment: My point is about your question. You only mentioned symptoms without describing any reproducible Node.js code. Is all Node.js code encountering the same issue as yours? Your question should include essential details about how to identify and address the problem. You haven't provided your actual Node.js code, details about the port being used, or demonstrated any effort in searching for existing solutions.

Comment: ok I'll add it rn

Comment: Thanks your for your understanding, I will recover your down score if you update with reproducible node.js code.